# How to differentiate Dart types

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, bwu-datagrid

I have the following types:

```dart
class AddressEditor extends TextEditor {}
class TypeEditor extends TextEditor {}
```

I tried to identify the editors as such:

```dart
void validationErrorHandler( ValidationError e )
{
  var editor = e.editor;
  if( editor is AddressEditor )
   print( editor.runtimeType.toString() ) // prints TextEditor

  if( editor is TypeEditor )
   print( editor.runtimeType.toString() ) // prints TextEditor
}
```

If I use mirrors

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors'; 

getTypeName(dynamic obj) 
{
  return reflect(obj).type.reflectedType.toString();
}

void validationErrorHandler( ValidationError e )
{
  var editor = e.editor;
  if( editor is AddressEditor )
   print( getTypeName( editor ) ) // prints TextEditor

  if( editor is TypeEditor )
   print( getTypeName( editor ) ) // prints TextEditor
}
```

Why is the editor type `TypeEditor` and `AddressEditor` not being identified? Yes, I know that either is a `TextEditor`, but is there any way to identify the `TypeEditor` or the `AddressEditor` in Dart.

I need to make these identification to work with the result of the validation.

Thanks

Comment: If you need to compile your code to JavaScript, do not use dart:mirrors unless you are OK with very large output.

Comment: Thanks Seth. But I was desperate to find a solution at any cost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

It turns out that `TextEditor` has a method `newInstance()` which is called to acquire new editor instances by `BWU Datagrid` (basically `TextEditor` is a factory and the implementation in one).

Because `TypeEditor` and `AddressEditor` don't override this method, internally pure `TextEditor` instances are created.

To get the desired behavior you need to override `newInstance` and implement the constructor used by this method. Because the constructor in `TextEditor` is private it can not be reused and needs to be copied (I'll reconsider this design). The first two lines of the copied constructor need to be adapted a little.

The AddressEditor would then look like

```dart
class AddressEditor extends TextEditor {
  AddressEditor() : super();

  @override
  TextEditor newInstance(EditorArgs args) {
    return new AddressEditor._(args);
  }

  AddressEditor._(EditorArgs args) {
    this.args = args;
    $input = new TextInputElement()
      ..classes.add('editor-text');
    args.container.append($input);
    $input
      ..onKeyDown.listen((KeyboardEvent e) {
      if (e.keyCode == KeyCode.LEFT || e.keyCode == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      }
    })
      ..focus()
      ..select();
  }
}
```

The `TypeEditor` is the same just a different class and constructor name.

**ORIGINAL**

I'm pretty sure that the above example with `is` works fine and that the problem lies somewhere else (that these values are not `AddressEditors` or `TypeEditors` but just `TextEditors`.

```dart
class TextEditor {}

class AddressEditor extends TextEditor {}
class TypeEditor extends TextEditor {}

void main() {
  check(new AddressEditor());
  check(new TypeEditor());
  check(new TextEditor());
}

void check(TextEditor editor) {
  if(editor is AddressEditor) print('AddressEditor: ${editor.runtimeType}');
  if(editor is TypeEditor) print('TypeEditor: ${editor.runtimeType}');
  if(editor is TextEditor) print('TextEditor: ${editor.runtimeType}');
}
```

output

```dart
AddressEditor: AddressEditor
TextEditor: AddressEditor

TypeEditor: TypeEditor
TextEditor: TypeEditor

TextEditor: TextEditor
```

Comment: I would like to add a link to a file on my compute to show the entire component but cannot find a way to do it in the comment. If you know how please suggest same.

Comment: Create a Gist at GitHub and add a link to your question.

Comment: Attempting new AddressEditor() always throws the following exception ||| Exception: No constructor 'AddressEditor' declared in class 'AddressEditor'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'AddressEditor'
Receiver: Type: class 'AddressEditor'
Arguments: [...] (http://localhost:8080/epimss_design.html.12.dart:105)  ||| and failure to display the grid.

Comment: Your are right there was another line missing. I added it (the first line after the class declaration)

Comment: Thanks for helping me overcoming this hurdle Gunter.